Why do closed shells have a SOC split?
Why do the energy states of closed shells behave like in the one electron case?
Imagine an atom with one electron in the $2p$ orbital. $l=1$ and $s=1/2$, so spin orbit coupling leads to two levels with a total anglular momentum $j=|l-s|=1/2$ and $|l+s|=3/2$ also called $p_{1/2}$ and $p_{3/2}$.
If there are 2 electrons in the $2p$ orbital, the lowest energy level resulting from coupling of spins and orbital moments is determined by LS-coupling and Hunds rules as $^{3}P_{0}$. But there are also higher energy levels possible like $^{1}S_{0}$, $^{3}P_{1}$, $^{3}P_{2}$, and $^{1}D_{2}$.
Adding more electrons results in similar complicated results. But as soon as the orbital is full, the splitting follows again the behavior of one electron and the states are again denoted as $p_{1/2}$ and $p_{3/2}$, just that now all 6 states are filled and can be probed with spectroscopy methods.
I know that full orbitals have no orbital or spin moment, but why so electrons then still exhibit spin-orbit-coupling with themselves, even though their own moment is also needed for the compensation of the others?
